# NumberFormatter's formatCurrency() output differs between currencies

Tags: php

Trying to format the number as a currency amount and add the relative ISO code as suffix.

```
$NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(MY_LOCALE, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$NumberFormatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, "");
$NumberFormatter->formatCurrency($Amount, $CurrencyCode="EUR");
```

This will produce "10,00" if $CurrencyCode=EUR but "10,00 DKK" or "10,00 RUB" for $CurrencyCode=DKK, $CurrencyCode=RUB

Why isn't it behaving consistently?

I would like it to return just the amount, without currency symbol nor ISO code, so that I can add the ISO code afterwards.

Using PHP 8.2.8 on a Debian.

Comment: PHP is mostly a front-end for some very complex third-party library that does the heavy lifting, and unfortunately documentation is not always ideal. At [NumberFormatter::setSymbol()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.setsymbol.php) it says "This API is not supported for rule-based formatters." (how do you know if a formatter is rule based? I don't know) and a user comment provides some hints: https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.setsymbol.php#124153

Answer (score 0):

That's the point of the `NumberFormatter` class. It uses a huge set of rules that have been compiled for each `Locale`. If that locale's rules say only include the number (for instance, if the locale matches the existing currency), then it will only show that. But if you specify a currency code that does is different, based on the rules, will likely display the currency so the user does not get confused over what currency is being displayed. The rules are based on what a majority of people generally expect as far as formatting currency or numbers in general for the specified locale.

That being said, if you just want a basic formatted number, you can just use the DECIMAL basic formatter:

```php
$NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(MY_LOCALE, NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$NumberFormatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
$NumberFormatter->format($Amount); // 10.00 or 10,00; Depending on locale rules
```

You can then add your own currency symbol and/or codes. However, the way your code was set up was *mostly* correct and would provide the proper symbol and/or code in the correct locations for the locale. Adding them on your own may confuse people in certain locales.

Comment: The point of using formatCurrency(), other than the fraction digits separator ("." vs ",") was to display the currency-specific amount of fraction digits. You've solved this by hardcoding it / declaring it explicitly ("2"). I guess that works in most cases (see https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/currency-codes). Also, in my case MY_LOCALE is set to "it_IT" and, using the exact same locale, if DKK it shows "DKK" after the amount whereas if EUR it shows nothing after the amount. I think a better approach would be to instantiate it with NumberFormatter::CURRENCY and get the number [...]

Comment: [...] of fraction digits and then format it as a number and add the currency ISO code afterwards.

Comment: Unless the number of fraction digits is derived from the locale in use and not by the currency, in which case I have it all wrong conceptually.

Comment: $NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(MY_LOCALE, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY); ->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, $CurrencyCode), ->->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, ""), ->format($Amount) seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$Locale = "it_IT";
$CurrencyCode = "JPY";
$Amount = 100.50;

$NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter($Locale, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$NumberFormatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, $CurrencyCode);
$NumberFormatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, "");
echo $NumberFormatter->format($Amount) ." ". $CurrencyCode;
```

The above will: a) remove the currency symbol, b) retain the currency-specific number of fraction digits, c) retain the locale-specific fraction digits and thousands separator chars, d) add the ISO currency code after the formatted amount